# Issue in Parallel foreach regarding Regex

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I need help in converting this for loop into a parallel forloop.

```
public void spellchecker()
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
    {       
        using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff", "en_US.dic"))
        {
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(GetRichTextBox().Text, @"\w+"))
            {
                string word = match.Value;
                Font fnt = GetRichTextBox().Font;
                Color color;
                if (!hunspell.Spell(word))
                {
                    fnt = new Font(fnt.FontFamily, fnt.Size, FontStyle.Underline);
                    color = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    fnt = new Font(fnt.FontFamily, fnt.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
                    color = Color.Black;
                }

                GetRichTextBox().Select(match.Index, match.Length); // Selecting the matching word.
                GetRichTextBox().SelectionColor = color;
                GetRichTextBox().SelectionStart = GetRichTextBox().TextLength; // Resetting the selection.
                GetRichTextBox().SelectionLength = 0;
            }                            
        }
    }));


}
```

This was my implementation when I tried to implement the parallel for loop. I keep getting an error saying "`Arguments for method'Parallel.ForEach<TSource>(IEnumereable<TSourcce>,Action<TSource>`)' cannot be inferred from the usage"

```
Parallel.ForEach(Regex.Matches(GetRichTextBox().Text, @"\w+"), match => {
    string word = match.Value;
    Font fnt = GetRichTextBox().Font;
    Color color;
    if (!hunspell.Spell(word))
    {
        fnt = new Font(fnt.FontFamily, fnt.Size, FontStyle.Underline);
        color = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        fnt = new Font(fnt.FontFamily, fnt.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
        color = Color.Black;
    }

    GetRichTextBox().Select(match.Index, match.Length); // Selecting the matching word.
    GetRichTextBox().SelectionColor = color;
    GetRichTextBox().SelectionStart = GetRichTextBox().TextLength; // Resetting the selection.
    GetRichTextBox().SelectionLength = 0;
});
```

Comment: Try `GetRichTextBox<String>()` and turn the lambda into an `Action<String>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parallel.ForEach() wants `IEnumerable<T>` for its first parameter. `TSource` has to be inferred from that type argument, because the second parameter is a lambda expression with no declared type for its own parameter. [Regex.Matches(string, string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w(v=vs.110).aspx) returns `MatchCollection`, which implements non-generic `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, *not* `IEnumerable<T>`. It predates generics. So there's no way for the compiler to infer what `TSource` is.

But we know `TSource` should be `Match`. So use `Cast<T>()`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Regex.Matches(GetRichTextBox().Text, @"\w+").Cast<Match>(), 
    match => {
```

---

### Points of interest

You could explicitly say that the lambda's parameter is `Match`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Regex.Matches(GetRichTextBox().Text, @"\w+"), (Match match) =>
```

And you would no longer get the type inference error. However, you'd still get an error about the IEnumerable, because `MatchCollection` still won't implement generic `IEnumerable<T>`:

> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' to '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>`'

---

Incidentally, this is why you can't use `var` in a `foreach` on `MatchCollection` without explicitly declaring the loop variable as `Match` or casting it in the loop body: Based on everything the compiler knows, `m` is `object`.

```
foreach (var m in Regex.Matches("foo", "[0-9]"))
{
    var caps = m.Captures;
}
```

> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Captures' and no extension method 'Captures' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)